# Laravel - Как посмотреть БД postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, laravel

Дали приложение кабинета пользователя на laravel, как посмотреть все настройки БД и открыть её саму?

Comment: http://proft.me/2013/06/9/postgresql-spravochnik-po-komandam-psql-pg_dump/

Comment: https://www.pgadmin.org/